# Set PySpark Serializer in PySpark Builder

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am using PySpark 2.1.1 and am trying to set the serializer when using Spark Submit. In my application, I initialize the SparkSession.builder as follows

```
print("creating spark session")
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("AppName").\
config("driver-library-path","libPath")).\
config("driver-java-options",driverJavaOptions).\
enableHiveSupport().\
config("deploy-mode","client").\
config("spark.serializer","PickleSerializer").\
config("spark.executor.instances",100).\
config("spark.executor.memory","4g").\
getOrCreate()
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PickleSerializer
```

What is the right way to initialize the serializer? I realize Pickle is default but I want to know for if I use one of the other supported serializers as well.

Answer (score 2):

`spark.serializer` is used to set Java serializer. For Python serializer use `serializer` argument of `SparkContext`

```
from pyspark.serializers import PickleSerializer

conf = SparkConf().set(...)
sc  = SparkContext(conf=conf, serializer=PickleSerializer())
```

Once `SparkContext` is ready you can  use it to initialize `SparkSession` explicitly:

```
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.sparkContext is sc

## True
```

or implicitly ([it will use `SparkContext.getOrCreate`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/64817c423c0d82a805abd69a3e166e5bfd79c739/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L174)):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext is sc

## True
```

Comment: While all this is true, I could not figure out how to do this from a spark submit style job. I'm trying to launch a PySpark job with Apache Livy.